# coupling in transmission line

Tags: antenna, transmission-line, pcb-antenna, coupling

I have a very basic and rather silly question which I have not found any suitable answer yet.

Suppose I have 2 transmission lines. One carrying a high frequency sinusoidal signal. Is there coupling in a 2nd transmission line close to the 1st one if:

1) The second transmission line is an open circuit?

2) The second transmission line is properly grounded?

Will there be a potential difference between the edges of the second transmission line in either case?

If NO, then why and if YES, then will it result in reverse coupling?

Comment: Great question. Can you indicate already what type of transmission line you're intending to use (balanced vs unbalanced) (i.e. twin-lead vs coax)?

Comment: Well, I am interested in unbalanced line but for a clear concept I would also like to know how it will differ from balanced lines.

Comment: I guess as long as there's capacitance between the lines there will be some kind of coupling. The greater the capacitance (e.g. lines closer together) the greater the effect. One thing to consider is that a mismatched impedance will send rf on the outside of coax. The greater the mismatch, the more you'll pick up on a nearby other transmission line. An open or short circuit is probably the biggest mismatch you can get.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I have 2 transmission lines. One carrying a high frequency
>   sinusoidal signal. Is there coupling in a 2nd transmission line close
>   to the 1st one

The problem you appear to have is that you are failing to recognize that all cables, wires and electrical connections are or can be regarded as transmission lines.

If you accepted this truth your question would become trivial i.e. "suppose there are two wires and one carries a signal, is there coupling from this wire to the next".

The answer always will be yes of course.